# Using jQuery, css not changing

Tags: jquery, css

I've assigned one of up to five (ListNumberOld is between 1 and 5) `p` elements as follows:

```
PreviousSelection = $(this).siblings(".result").find("p:nth-child('" + ListNumberOld + "')");
```

I'm now trying to update it's CSS:

```
PreviousSelection.css("background-color","black")
```

But the css is not changing, is there anything reason from the above code?  I've even tried to display the current css using:

```
alert (PreviousSelection.css("background-color")); << FIXED
```

...but the alert does't appear << FIXED

I've even tried adding/removing styles:

```
        CurrentSelection = $(this).siblings(".result").find("p:nth-child(" + ListNumber + ")");
          CurrentSelection.removeClass("resultSelectedNot");
          CurrentSelection.removeClass("resultSelected");
```

...but again, nothing happens

---

HTML as requested.  Updating .css or add/removeClass works for the .result, but not for children.

```
<form id="frmTransListRecord_00002" name="frmTransListRecord_00002" method="post">        
<div id="idTransListRecordLineColWrapper_TransID" style="display: none" class="clTransListRecordLineColWrapper">            
<div class="clTransactionListingCol_ID clTransListFieldValues">ID</div>         
<div class="clTransactionListingCol_ID clTransListFieldValues">           
  <input type="text" name="txtTransactionID" value="-" readonly="" size="6" class="clTransField clTextAlignCenter clTransValue_TransID">              
  <input type="text" name="txtTransactionID_B" value="-" hidden="" size="6" class="clTransField clTextAlignCenter clTransValue_TransID">            </div>        </div>          
<div id="idTransListRecordLineColWrapper_AccountID" class="clTransListRecordLineColWrapper">            
<div><span>Account</span></div>         
<div>             <input class="clParentTransID" hidden="" value="TMP">           <input type="text" id="txtAccountID" hidden="" readonly="" class="clTransField">            <input type="text" id="txtAccountIDName" class="clLiveSearchAccountChild clTransField" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Accounts...">             
<div class="result" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: thin solid; padding: 0.5em;">
  <p id="1" class="x">[2]|[ENTRY 1]</p>
  <p id="2" class="x">[3]|[ENTRY 2]</p>
  <p id="3" class="x">[4]|[ENTRY 3]</p>
  <p id="4" class="x">[5]|[ENTRY 4]</p>
</div>              
</div>         
</div>        
</form>
```

Note that this is dynamically added, both the .result and the child `p`s.

Comment: I usually do `.css({'background-color':'black'})`

Comment: The weird thing is, it works for the parent element, a div, but not for the child 'p's.  Looking at Chrome's inspector, it's refusing to add either the CSS or the Class to the children.

Comment: Post the HTML so we verify the accuracy of your selector.

Comment: added to initial question.

Comment: If your `<p>` really do have IDs on them, why not just target those instead of getting fancy?

Comment: Because there are multiple rows that the live search can be called from.

Comment: IDs should be unique, but regardless, no errors in the console? Have you tried `nth-of-type()` or tried combining `result` with `p:nth` as one selector?

Comment: Not yet, will try later. In Chrome's Inspector, the .result div and the child 'p's flash when a change is attempted, if that says anything.

Comment: I'm assuming `this` refers to the input, but given what you have it should work as demonstrated by this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r2jkm33y/1/ Because yours is not working I'm thinking you have some styling interfering somewhere, but without actually seeing your live example it's hard to say.

Comment: This actually turned out not to be a 'other styling overriding', but a misstep in the jQuery. It was re inserting the results when the user used the arrow up/down, effectively removing any temporary highlights.

Answer (score 1):

The number in nth-child(n) shouldn't be in quotes, so it should be

```
PreviousSelection = $(this).siblings(".result").find("p:nth-child(" + ListNumberOld + ")");
```

(removed the single quotes)

And use a `:` and additional curly brackets in this code:

```
PreviousSelection.css({"background-color": "black"});
```

Comment: Well the alert works, but the css is still not changing.  I've exactly the same, but for CurrentSelection, a different nth-child, that should change it to a diff colour, but nothing happens.

Comment: If its a single CSS property you can do `.css("background-color","black")`

Answer (score 1):

The `nth-child` accepts an integer value and should not be included in quotes, So just append the value `ListNumberOld` without the quotes.

```
 PreviousSelection = $(this).siblings(".result")
                            .find("p:nth-child("+ListNumberOld+")");
```